# login to any user account in application

Tags: asp.net-4.0, form-authentication

I have a asp.net application which is using form authentication, as this application is going to be online and we are looking for a secret login page by which we can login to any user account with only his username.

Is that possible?

**EDIT**

Or if there is any way I can read password from sql server aspnet_Users table, If I can convert it into plain text and use a general method to login. That would work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "convert" it back. All hash functions are one-way only so there is no way to get original value.

**Edit**: There are 'rainbow' tables, which is basically dictionary of text-hash mapping. But they won't help you, because passwords are also salted in default Membership implementation.

Comment: Is there any way I can login via other user account ?

Comment: Well, you can, but then you will violate all rules of security. If i was one of your users i would be very disappointed to know about this. You know, there are many ways how to protect user account even from admin. This is one of them. Not completely bulletproof, but...

Comment: I can understand that but my client wants that :-(

Comment: Then explain to your client that it is high security risk! One example: junior employee somehow gets CEO account... Imagine THAT! Sometimes clients has strange requirements, then it is our job as developers to explain all pros and also cons of it.